# Looking for old Assembler-like bot language on C64

Tags: memory, bots, programming-languages, c64, corewars

In a discussion with a friend I was recently reminded of a fascinating idea from the days of Commodore C64. Unfortunately, googling brought no results, which might be due to the fact that I don't even know what to google for. So, I would like to ask for help here...

In a nutshell, I remember there once was a very simple, almost Assembler-like programming language that was used exclusively for programs that were battling each other in computer memory by overwriting each other. Personally, I played around with it on a C64, but it might have been ported to other systems, as well. It might have been called "program war" or something like that and for a while there were big communities running competitions and championships.

Is anyone old enough to know, what I'm talking about, and could help me with some info? :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are remembering [Core War](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_War) where the assembly language was called Redcode and specifically **Core Wars Pro for C64** (see [mobygames.com](https://www.mobygames.com/game/core-wars-pro), [corewar.co.uk](https://corewar.co.uk/corewarsep.htm))

Comment: YES, that's exactly it. Thank you very much for your answer... I had almost given up to find a reference to this. Very much appreciated! :D

Comment: added another link which has links to other Memory Array Redcode Simulator (MARS) implementations.